# Accessing data in GET form and posting to results page (Django)

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to create a form that takes inputs and uses these inputs to create an output that's posted to a results page. I've searched everywhere and can't understand how to post the data (in the case below, 'country' and 'culture') to the results_view.

```
# view.py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render

from form.forms import InputForm

def get_list(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
    form = InputForm(request.GET)
        if form.is_valid():
            country = form.cleaned_data['country']
            culture = form.cleaned_data['culture']

            return results_view(form)

    else:
         form = InputForm()

    return render(request, 'form/index.html', {'form': form})

def results_view(form):
    text = form.restaurant

    c = {'output' : text}
    return render(form, 'form/results.html', c)
```

and

```
# forms.py
from django import forms

class InputForm(forms.Form):
    country = forms.CharField(label='country', max_length=100) 
    cuisine = forms.CharField(label='cuisine', max_length=100)
```

How can I access the inputs and use them as the text in 'results_view'? Additionally, if I want to pass these results as an input argument for another python function (say a function that maps country name to latitude and longitude), how can I incorporate this into views.py?  Thanks a lot!

Comment: Follow the django tutorial https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial01/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to redirect to another function, just render this another template

```
# view.py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render

from form.forms import InputForm

def get_list(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
    form = InputForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            country = form.cleaned_data['country']
            culture = form.cleaned_data['culture']

            c = {'country' : country, 'culture'... whatever you get}
            return render(form, 'form/results.html', c)

    else:
         form = InputForm()

    return render(request, 'form/index.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: thanks! Does this mean that in urls.py, I just need one urlpattern? Or should I have two, something like that:  urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.get_list, name='get_list'),
    path('form/results.html', views.get_list, name='results'),
]

Comment: How can I account for both ' ' and 'form/results.html' in one url pattern though?

Comment: Try this last edit, you're accessing both though now,